# Scala: Function has return type of interface, I need implementing class

Tags: java, scala, collections

I need to use a function that has return type java.util.Collection. I know that for my use case this function will always return an ArrayList (which implements Collection).
I am trying to write a statement like:

`val secMasterPrimaryRic: util.ArrayList[JsonNode] = functionThatReturnsCollection()`

but I get the error:

`Error:(88, 87) type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.Collection[org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode]
 required: java.util.ArrayList[org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode]`

In Java I would probably be able to cast it directly. I am trying to avoid using `asInstanceOf` as I have been told that's pretty slow. Is there any other way to get an ArrayList?

Comment: `asInstanceOf` is just how you write a cast in Scala, so it isn't any slower than in Java. It should be avoided for exactly the same reasons you should avoid casts in Java, except 1) this is more ingrained in Scala culture; 2) the idiom of first checking `instanceof` and then casting to the type is replaced by pattern matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is wrong casting `Collection` to `ArrayList` because `Collection` can has any implementation.

I would suggest 2 options

- either change signature of `functionThatReturnsCollection` so it returns `ArrayList`
- or create new `ArrayList` from `Collection`

  `val secMasterPrimaryRic: util.ArrayList[JsonNode] = new util.ArrayList[JsonNode](functionThatReturnsCollection())`

Comment: is this better than `val secMasterPrimaryRic: util.ArrayList[JsonNode] = functionThatReturnsCollection()).asInstanceOf[util.ArrayList[JsonNode]]`?

Comment: yes, it is better. `asInstanceOf` is unsafe operation that can throw exception in runtime.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a function that returns a type `X` but want a type `Y` where `Y` has an "is a" relationship, then you can do the following:

```
val myValue: TypeIWant = myFunction() match{
  case x: TypeIWant => x
  case y => convertToTypeIWant(y)
}
```

That way you can honor both the underlying types and any implementation which needs conversion without having to resort to the use of an unsafe cast.